# Is there a list of locale codes of countries that use commas instead of decimal points available online?

Tags: javascript, localization, formatting

For formatting purposes I need a list of locale codes of countries that use commas instead of decimal points and I'm wondering if one already exists online before I go through the painstaking task of creating one myself.

The specific problem I'm dealing with is that I add either ".00" or ",00" to the end of a number and I need to check if the user's locale code is that of a country that uses either, in JavaScript. I previously had it to check if the index of "." is -1 as I only had "en-US" in mind but this doesn't work now if I have to take into account different locales.

Answer (score 0):

I made up a list myself. I think I got all of them.

```
commaLocaleCodes = ['AM', 'AR', 'AT', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BE', 'BG', 'BO', 'BR', 'BY',
                    'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CM', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK',
                    'EC', 'EE', 'ES', 'FI', 'FO', 'FR', 'GE', 'GL',  'HR', 'HU',
                    'ID', 'IS', 'IT', 'KZ', 'LB', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MD', 'MK', 'MO', 'MZ',
                    'NL', 'NO', 'PE', 'PL', 'PT', 'PY', 'RO', 'RS', 'RU',
                    'SE', 'SI', 'SK', 'TN', 'TR', 'UA', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VE', 'VN', 'ZA']
```

Comment: Careful with this list, 'HR' definetelly uses decimal point. Also 'CA' uses decimal comma when speaking french and point when speaking english

Comment: HR uses decimal comma according to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_decimal_comma